# jquery ui tabs rendering whole web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Here is the page in question:
http://sl7-dev.mailordercentral.com/roex/PC-95-180-tabs/productinfo/01180/

Here is the tabs code page:
http://sl7-dev.mailordercentral.com/roex/tmpDev.html

When I put

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
```

in the header Each tab shows the whole web page inside the tab AND each tabs content below.

if I put it in the footer I get an unrendered div/li combo instead of tabs.

Any ideas on where to look?

Comment: Maybe post your code?

Comment: If you have firebug add-on in firefox, check your console. Few issues with ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 

})(jQuery);

jquery...hoto.js (line 923)
GET http://sl7-dev.mailordercentral.com/roex/
 
200 OK
  523ms 
jquery-1.9.1.js (line 8526)
TypeError: $(...).prettyPhoto is not a function
 

...quare' /*  pp_default / light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_squar...

initia...hoto.js (line 3)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://sl7-dev.mailordercentral.com/resources/demos/style.css"